# Dynamically register routes for MVC actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, routes

I understand why routes exist and how having a very hard-coded set of routes can be useful.

But, I keep finding myself in these kinds of situations:

```
 public PartialViewResult GetAssetHistory(string assetCode, string mode)

 public PartialViewResult GetAssetData(string assetCode)

 public PartialViewResult GetAssetData2(string assetCode, string mode, int assetParam)
```

I do not want to have to hard-code a route of

```
Asset/{action}/{assetCode}/{mode}/{assetParam}
```

It would be much better if I could just have all routes, or all controllers with an attribute set to dynamically create routes such that the first route value maps to the first parameter (e.g. assetCode) and the second route value maps to the second parameter of the action (e.g. mode), and so on?

I understand this would probably require reflection, but is there any reason why doing this could be very bad, or should not be done, or can't be done?

Bonus points for an example of doing this in the RouteConfig.cs

Comment: How will you give bonus points? ;)

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Turns out it is possible. The following is a sample, it should be modified to add the rest of the routes supported by the site.

- Use a custom attribute to detect which actions should be used for dynamic route creation

---

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class DynamicUrlAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

---

- Decorate your actions with your custom attribute

---

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    [DynamicUrl]
    public ActionResult Index(int param2)
    {
        return View(param2);
    }

    [DynamicUrl]
    public ActionResult MultipleParams(int param1, int param2)
    {
        return View(new { param1, param2 });
    }
}
```

---

- Generate the routes by means of reflection

---

```
public static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Detect all the actions whose route should be generated dynamically
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>List of actions</returns>
    private static IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetTypesWithHelpAttribute()
    {
        foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
            {
                foreach (var method in type.GetMethods())
                {
                    if (method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DynamicUrlAttribute), 
                                            true).Length > 0)
                    {
                        yield return method;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the list of routes to add to the Route Table
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>List of routes</returns>
    public static List<Route> GetRoutes()
    {
        List<Route> routes = new List<Route>();

        foreach (var action in GetTypesWithHelpAttribute())
        {
            string controllerName = action.DeclaringType.Name.Replace("Controller","");
            string actionName = action.Name;
            List<string> parameters = new List<string>();
            int index = 0;
            foreach (var parameterInfo in action.GetParameters())
            {
                parameters.Add(GetParamName(action, index++));
            }
            string parameterSection = action.GetParameters().Length > 0 ?
                    parameters.Aggregate("", (a, b) => $"{a}/{{{b}}}") 
                    : "";
            string finalRoute = $"dynamic/{controllerName}/{actionName}{parameterSection}";
            routes.Add(new Route(
                url: finalRoute,
                defaults: new RouteValueDictionary( 
                    new { 
                        controller = controllerName, 
                        action = actionName }),
                routeHandler: new MvcRouteHandler()
            ));
        }
        return routes;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the name of the parameter by using reflection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="method">Method information</param>
    /// <param name="index">Parameter index</param>
    /// <returns>Parameter name</returns>
    public static string GetParamName(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, int index)
    {
        string retVal = string.Empty;

        if (method != null && method.GetParameters().Length > index)
            retVal = method.GetParameters()[index].Name;

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

---

- Add the detected routes to the route collection

---

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        foreach (var route in Extensions.GetRoutes())
        {
            routes.Add(route);
        }
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

For this code you will end up with the following two valid url routes

1. /dynamic/Sample/Index/2
2. /dynamic/Sample/MultipleParams/1/2

### Original (Not valid)

<s>Imagine the other way around. Let's say we have a view with this content</s>

```
@Url.Action("Action","Controller", 
    new { 
        assetCode = "code", 
        mode = "mode", 
        assetParam = "assetParam", 
        someOtherProperty = "someOtherProperty" 
    })
```

Now, which url do you want to be created?

- /Controller/Action/code
- /Controller/Action/code/mode
- /Controller/Action/code/mode/assetParam
- /Controller/Action/code/mode/assetParam/someOtherProperty (even worse, cause that one doesn't even exist)
- /Controller/Action/someOtherProperty/code/assetParam/mode (way even more worse, this might be a possible url, since there is no information whatsoever about the order in which the url should be generated)

When you define the 3 routes, it's clear for the framework which is the URL to be created. If that was somehow dynamic, it will be impossible for the framework to correctly generate the valid corresponding url. That is, unless you start filling your controllers and actions with custom attributes, and before start doing that, it makes more sense to actually use RouteAttribute and/or defining the actual routes in the route table.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this through implementing [IRouteHandler](https://dzone.com/articles/iroutehandler-aspnet-mvc).

1. Create a custom IRouteHandler
2. The custom IRouteHandler will figure out the controller, action, parameters etc.
3. The custom IRouteHandler will then simply pass the request to the regular MvcHandler.
4. The MvcHandler now knows which controller and action will process the request.

The custom IRouteHandler will simply be like this:

```
public sealed class UrlRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var routeData = requestContext.RouteData.Values;
        var url = routeData["urlRouteHandler"] as string;

        // The class UrlHandler will have all the code for figuring things out
        var route = UrlHandler.GetRoute(url);

        routeData["url"] = route.Url;
        routeData["controller"] = route.Controller;
        routeData["action"] = route.Action;
        // other stuff to add

        // Now let MvcHandler process the request.
        return new MvcHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

Register the handler in `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "IUrlRouteHandler",
            "{*urlRouteHandler}").RouteHandler = new UrlRouteHandler();
```

Most of the hard work has been done [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dynamic-and-friendly-url-using-mvc/) by this nice fellow. You can just follow that. The only difference between what you want to do and what has been done in that article is: You want to figure stuff from the URL by convention, he is figuring things out using URLs stored in the database.

The full source code for the article is on [GitHub](https://github.com/fabiosilvalima/FSL.DynamicAndFriendlyUrlUsingMvc/tree/fe2bb94e505e571c18234ae4e895a6601e1f350f).